# How to produce modulus 3 from loop counter in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, count, counter

Can a counter be set up to separate the first item in a query, then cycle through the remaining items in groups of 3? So the logic is:

```
item 1 - {separate id entirely}
item 2 class=1, item 3 class=2, item 4 class=3, RESET item 5 class=1, etc
```

I'm not sure how to do the count minus one for the class, and then reset after every 3rd item (item 2, 3, 4 reset for 5, 6, 7 reset for 8, 9, 10).

I'm trying to remove the "featured block" ACF rows and set the first item in ACF "content areas" to be in the "feature" section. This way in the content edit screen the repeater rows can be moved around without recreating content from one section to another.

```
<?php if( have_rows('featured_block') ): while( have_rows('featured_block') ): the_row(); if(get_row_layout() == 'feature' ): ?> 
<section class="feature"> ...feature stuff...</section>
<?php endif; ?><!-- end feature --> <?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- end featured block -->
<section class="products clear">
    <?php $count = 0;
 // check for rows 
if( have_rows('content_areas') ): 
     ?>
<?php // add a counter
while( have_rows('content_areas') ): the_row(); $count++;  ?>
<article class="th<?php echo $count; ?> m1">
<?php // reset counter if 3 has been reached
    if ($count==3){
    $count=0;
    } ?> ...rows stuff...</article>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php  endif; // content_areas ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give an example of what you want and show what you have tried? It's not very clear what you're asking, much less what it has to do with PHP or Wordpress.

Comment: I'm using Advance Custom Fields with wordpress on a site. The goal is to have a repeater area in the content edit page, with the first content area being put in a featured section of the html, and the rest of the content areas in a separate section in rows of 3. I can do this with a separate content area for the first block but then have to recreate the content when it moves into the rowed section below. I don't know enough programming or math to figure it out.

Comment: It's likely that if I could figure out _how_ to ask the question, the answer would present itself :) I'll try adding code to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be after something like:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach( $items as $item ){

    if( $counter <= 1 ) continue;
    $class = ( ( ( $counter - 2 ) % 3 ) + 1 );
    $counter++;

}
```

So you would have this class list:

```
counter         class
-------         --------
1                nothing
2                1
3                2
4                3
5                1
6                2
7                3
```

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for, but I'm getting an invalid argument error for foreach so this problem is beyond my limited abilities.

Comment: What's the error you are facing? whats ur loop structure. you did not provide any code, and nobody can help u, until u provide some useful information. Its a better idea to provide some code, instead of plenty of descriptions.

Comment: it was a `foreach` error that I suspect is due to `$item` that I didn't know how to fix. I know the problem is not with the code you gave. Thank you for the tips, I'll try to step back and be clearer next time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the first item in a repeater row separate, I added a true/false if an item should be featured. That row(s) is styled first, then the rest of the rows begin counting. This is the code

```
<?php $counter = 0;
         // check for rows 
    if( have_rows('repeater_name') ): 
           while( have_rows('repeater_name') ): the_row();  ?>
            <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'feature' ) ): ?><!--if the feature true/false checked to set true-->
                <section class="feature">
                    <!--pull in content area repeater rows that have feature set true-->
                </section>
        <section class="products clear"><!--if this is put after the else the section is repeated for each repeater-->
        <?php else: ?>

             <!--start counting the rest--> 
            <?php $counter++;  ?>   
                <article class="th<?php echo $counter; ?> m1">
    <?php // reset counter if 3 has been reached
        if ($counter==3){
        $counter=0;
        } ?>
                <!--pull in content area repeater rows that do NOT have feature set true-->
         </article>
            <?php endif; // end if have feature ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end repeater_name ?>
        </section>
<?php  endif; // repeater_name ?>
```